# Deleting versioned objects permanently from google cloud storage bucket after a period

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Am I able to permanently delete a `non-current`/`non-live` object a set number of days *after its deletion date* with a lifecycle rule?

From the [GCP documentation regarding managing lifecycles](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/managing-lifecycles#enable) it shows:

```js
{
  "lifecycle": {
    "rule": [
      {
        "action": {"type": "Delete"},
        "condition": {
          "age": 10,
          "isLive": false
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am not sure if this translates into deleting files that were **created** or **deleted** 10 days ago.

**NOTE: not concerned about the unit of `age` but rather the meaning in the context of `isLive` when `false`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To confirm, the age is in days. As it's shown in the Console option, it's in days. The REST API option just shows the option configured differently - as per their [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/managing-lifecycles#enable).

[image: Age]

Besides that, in the documentation [Resource representations](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets#resource-representations), that clarifies the Properties, says:

> Age of an object (in days). This condition is satisfied when an object reaches the specified age.

This way, confirming that the **Age that you mentioned is in days**.

In addition to that, as you mentioned, about permanently deleting after a date, you can give it a try using a [Cloud Storage Trigger](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage) - explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/extend-with-functions) as well - to execute a Cloud Function, that will run a function to delete non-current objects permanently.

You can find more information on how to do this deletions [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-object-versioning#delete).

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: many thanks for approaching this question. The focus is not the unit of "age" (it is very clear that it only accepts `days` as the unit). The focus of this question is whether "permanent deletion" can be rendered with a lifecycle rule such that it occurs any number of days since deletion (or an `age` based on the deletion date not the creation date). Again, thank you for the great answer - despite it being for a different question. I'll try to clean up my question if it's confusing to anyone else.

Comment: Hi @Marc no problem. Thanks for clarifying! As per the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/managing-lifecycles#delete_an_object), once an object is deleted, it's permanently deleted, not bene possible to restore it. Considering that, could you please clarify what do you mean by "permanent deletion"?

Comment: when you delete an object on a bucket that has versioning enabled it still retains the object but shifts it to a "non-current" state (such that it doesn't display when you do `gsutil ls gs://<bucket>` unless you do `gsutil ls -a gs://<bucket>`). It may be permanently deleted if that non-current object is also deleted.

Comment: Hi @Marc thanks for the clarification! I have updated my answer with more information.

Answer (score 1):

User enables Object Versioning to protect his Cloud Storage data from being overwritten or accidentally deleted.

One of the [lifecycle conditions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle) is:

> **IsLive:** This condition is typically only used in conjunction with object versioning. When set to false, this condition is satisfied for
>   any noncurrent version of an object. When set to true, this condition
>   is satisfied for the live version of an object. If you don't use
>   object versioning, all your objects are considered live and match when
>   IsLive is true.

**I am not sure if this translates into deleting files that were created or deleted 10 days ago.**

> Cloud Storage creates a noncurrent version of an object each time you
>   perform an **overwrite or delete** of the live version, as long as you do
>   not specify the generation number of the live version.

On you question the `isLive` is set to `false`, meaning that all the versions (overwrite or delete of live version) that satisfies the condition (10 days) will be deleted except the noncurrent version (live version).